# Angular, Azure.CreateBlobService not reading Environmental variables or values passed in?

Tags: html, angular, azure, typescript, azure-blob-storage

I'm using this function from the Azure Blob Service library: https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/global.html#createBlobService

But its not allowing me to, When specifying the environmental variables in environment.ts it throws up this error: ERROR Error: Credentials must be provided when creating a service client.

And when trying to pass in the ConnectionString it throws this error:  ERROR TypeError: crypto.createHmac is not a function

```
  var azure = require('azure-storage');
  var bs = azure.createBlobService();
  bs.createContainerIfNotExists('taskcontainer', {
    publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
  }, function(error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
      console.log("True");
      // if result = true, container was created.
      // if result = false, container already existed.
    }
  });
```

Has anyone had this problem before? would be great to see a solution

Comment: You are using the Nodejs library.

Comment: are you calling this method from your backend or from the angular app ?  I cant see in your code how you pass the connectionstring. Have you set this env variable `AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING` ?

Comment: Hey, Sorry I managed to get this working and noticed that I was trying to create a new Blob although earlier I was directly referencing it so didn't have to use the CreateblobService command at all for what I wanted to achieve

Comment: @Rob sorry to dig up an old issue but how did you resolve this? I'm getting exact same issue where keys are defined in .env but I get this error, specifically when testing via Mocha. Running the application normally works fine. Also, sometimes testing works fine without making any changes...

Comment: @Rob  i am also got the same error could you guys provide what you found?

Answer (score 0):

you should provide account name and storage key something like this:

```
var blobService = azure.createBlobService(environment.storage_account_name, environment.storage_key);
```